# How to fix NetworkManager being stuck on "PCI Ethernet connectiong"?

Tags: networking, networkmanager, manjaro, ethernet

I have a Thinkpad E14 running a current Manjaro.

While I can use Wifi just fine, I suddenly have a problem with my ethernet. When enabling ethernet, I see it being stuck on "PCI Ethernet Connecting" indefenitly.

[image]

I checked for relevant information in via `journalctl -f`, yet only one that pops up are:

```
Mai 02 16:19:13 000269 dbus-daemon[1308]: [session uid=1000 pid=1308] Activating service name='org.gnome.DejaDup' requested by ':1.60' (uid=1000 pid=1648 comm="/usr/lib/deja-dup/deja-dup-monitor")
Mai 02 16:19:13 000269 dbus-daemon[1308]: [session uid=1000 pid=1308] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.DejaDup'
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1472] device (enp2s0): state change: ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <warn>  [1651501154.1478] device (enp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1480] device (enp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1932] dhcp4 (enp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1953] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 1' (4bf98a2a-0d59-352a-9b65-d0f2e51545ca)
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1965] device (enp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 1' (4bf98a2a-0d59-352a-9b65-d0f2e51545ca)
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1974] device (enp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1984] device (enp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.1992] device (enp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Mai 02 16:19:14 000269 NetworkManager[724]: <info>  [1651501154.2006] dhcp4 (enp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
```

I am connected to a switch, which in turn is connected to a router. It worked in the past. I also tested the cable, it works on other machines and it used to work before. The issues persists after reboot.

How to further debug and how top get ethernet working again?

Comment: Related: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=232833

Comment: maybe just a loose cable?

Comment: @Andra Welp. It was a loose cable on the connection from router to switch.

Comment: actually I should apologize - now I noticed that you write that you tested the cable..damn why I comment without properly reading the text..

Comment: @Andra Thank you though in the end, your comment pointed me in the right direction anyway. Feel free to post an answer in the direction of "check ALL the cables" for me to upvote and accept.